# Транслятор кода на Python

Tags: php, c++, python

Хочу написать транслятор кода на python. Транслировать собираюсь php код в c++. 
Я вижу транслятор кода так: есть программа(.py), на вход которой подается имя файла(.php). Дальше программа читает этот файл и одновременно создает такой же файл, но уже с расширением .cpp. Во время чтения происходит парсинг первого файла, т.е. если в первом файле есть:

```
$name = "Alex"; 
echo $name;
```

то в файле .cpp должно быть следующее:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
     std::string name = "Alex";
     std::cout << name << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Правильно ли я вообще вижу, как работает транслятор?

Comment: Я вообще не понял, что нужно сделать. Из кода пхп получить код спп? Правильно? Или сразу запускать полученное на выполнение?

Comment: @levadny Добро пожаловать на StackO(verflow на русском. Пожалуйста, уделите немного времени нашим правилам: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour и   http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers для начала.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не все так просто. Для начала вам потребуется написать синтаксический анализатор, который будет заниматься анализом транслируемого кода (в вашем случае php).

Если вы пишитe интepпpeтaтop кaкoгo тo выcoкoypoвнeвoгo языкa, или вooбщe, цeлый кoмпилятop, тo пepвoe, чтo пpийдeт в гoлoвy пocлe изyчeния cyти вoпpoca - мeтoд peкypcивнoгo cпycкa. Тaк кaк вы решили использовать Python - обратите внимание на мoдyль spark.

Moдyль пpeдcтaвляeт в pacпopяжeниe нecкoлькo клaccoв - для лeкcичecкoгo и cинтaкcичecкoгo aнaлизa (GenericScanner, GenericParser), для построения дерева синтаксического разбора (GenericASTBuilder), для обхода этого дерева (GenericASTTraversal), и для поиска узлов в синтаксическом дереве (GenericASTMatcher).

Вот пример интерпретатора целочисленных математических выражений. Начинать нужно с лексического анализа. Суть лексического анализа в разборе входящего текста на последовательность элементарных составляющих - токенов. Это может быть оператор (к примеру + или -), идентификатор (имя переменной, метода, класса и т.д.) разделитель (запятая, двуеточие...) и прочие.

В этом деле поможет класс GenericScanner. Для начала нужно наследовать наш сканер от этого класса:

```
from spark import GenericScanner

class Scanner(GenericScanner):

    def __init__(self):
    # Инициализировать нужно обязательно!
    GenericScanner.__init__(self)
    # Создаем список, в котором будут сохранятся токены
    self.tokens = []
```

Токены будут сохранятся в виде простого класса-контейнера. Вот его код:

```
class Token:

    def __init__(self, type, value):
        """
        type - тип токена (оператор, идентификатор и т.д.)
        value - его значение
        """

        self.type = type
        self.value = value

        # Нужно реализовать еще пару методов для сравнения токенов
        # и для строкового представления 
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return self.type == other

        def __ne__(self, other):
            return not self == other

        def __repr__(self):
            return '%s(%r)' %(self.type, self.value)
```

Далее нужно создавать методы, в которых будут обрабатываться токены. Эти методы должны удовлетворять некоторым условиям - во первых, имя метода должно начинаться с "t_", во вторых, метод должен принимать один аргумент - собственно, токен. И в третьих - первая строка метода должна быть строкой документации, которая содержит в себе регулярное выражение с описанием данного токена. Напишем метод для распознавания целых чисел:

```
        def t_integer(self, token):
            r'\d+' # Только целые десятичные числа
           # Добавляем токен в список
           self.tokens.append(Token('INTEGER', int(token)
```

Далее методы для распознавания операторов:

```
        def t_operator(self, token):
            r'[\+\-\*\/]' # только плюс, минус, умножение и деление
            self.tokens.append(Token('OPERATOR', token))
```

Теперь нужен метод для обработки пробелов:

```
        def t_space(self, token):
            r'\s+' # Для любых символов пропуска
            # Пропускаем их
            pass
```

И, наконец, желательно перегрузить метод t_default - он вызывается в случае, если встреченный символ не описывается никаким предыдущим методом:

```
        def t_default(self, token):
            r'[\s\S]+' # Для любых символов
            # Синтаксическая ошибка!
            raise SyntaxError, str(token)
```

Сканер готов. Пользоваться им можно следующим образом:

scanner = Scanner()
scanner.tokenize(data)
tokens = scanner.tokens

Где data - сканируемый текст.

Итак, мы имеем сканнер, который обрабатывает текст, и на выходе выдает поток токенов (или ошибку в случае встречи незнакомого символа)

Как видите, все не так просто. Просто интересовался раньше этим вопросом, вспомнил, о данной статье, привел почти целиком для ознакомления. Далее разбирайтесь с вопросом сами.